# Skype windows broke

Tags: 14.04, skype

This is what I see when I open a new skype chat:

[image]

Why ? And how can I resolve ?

Comment: I have same problem. Ubuntu 14.04 . Skype latest available for download

Comment: I've been having this problem, particularly after suspending/resuming.
Any luck resolving this?